# Cost Suffix in Oracle Explain Plans

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have the following snippet of the explain plans below:

Explain Plan 1

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                    | Name                         | E-Rows |E-Bytes|E-Temp | Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |                              |        |       |       |    37M(100)|          |       |       |          |
...
|* 36 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | ZX_ACCOUNTS_U2               |      1 |    36 |       |     0   (0)|          |  1025K|  1025K|          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Explain Plan 2

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                    | Name                         | E-Rows |E-Bytes|E-Temp | Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |                              |        |       |       |   879T(100)|          |       |       |          |
...
|* 39 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | ZX_ACCOUNTS_U2               |      1 |    36 |       |     0   (0)|          |  1025K|  1025K|          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As I know, the total cost of Explain Plan 1 is 37 Millon. But I'm not sure with the Cost of Explain Plan 2. Is it 879 Thousand? or is it 879 Trillion?
I tried to find some documentation about the suffixes but I couldn't find any.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, T is trillion.  Note that you can't necessarily just compare the cost between plans for two different statements unless they happen to come from the same 10053 trace.  There is no guarantee that a plan with a cost of 879 trillion will take more time to actually run than a plan with a cost of 37 million.

Comment: @JustinCave thanks. yes they're the same the queries, I'm just experimenting with Hints. thanks!

Comment: They're not the same query if you're adding a hint, though.  Adding a hint can change the way that various operations are costed so you can't just compare costs and conclude that a hint does or does not produce a better plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explain plan numbers generally follow the [International System of Units prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes): K = kilo, M = mega, G = giga, T = tera, P = peta, and E = exa.

There are a few oddities in the numbering scheme. Explain plan uses an uppercase "K" for "kilo" when I would expect a lower case "k". There are some inconsistencies in when Oracle switches between prefixes - K, M, and G can have four digits, but T and P can only have three. And "E" only means "exa" for some numbers; really large numbers are always displayed as "18E".

Below are the different input and display numbers used by `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY`:

```
Number of rows           Explain Plan Output
-----------------------  -------------------
9                        |     9 |
99                       |    99 |
999                      |   999 |
9999                     |  9999 |
99999                    | 99999 |
999999                   |   999K|
9999999                  |  9999K|
99999999                 |    99M|
999999999                |   999M|
9999999999               |  9999M|
99999999999              |    99G|
999999999999             |   999G|
9999999999999            |  9999G|
99999999999999           |    99T|
999999999999999          |   999T|
9999999999999999         |    10P|
99999999999999999        |   100P|
999999999999999999       |   999P|
9999999999999999999      |    10E|
99999999999999999999     |    18E|
999999999999999999999    |    18E|
9999999999999999999999   |    18E|
```

Below is the code that generated the results:

```
--Create sample table that is only used for statistics.
--drop table test1;
create table test1(a number);

--How does the DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY handle large numbers?
declare
    v_lines sys.odcivarchar2list;
    v_num_rows number;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows           Explain Plan Output');
    dbms_output.put_line('-----------------------  -------------------');

    --Repeat the process for many numbers.
    for i in 1 .. 22 loop
        --Increase the number of digits.
        v_num_rows := rpad('9', i, '9');

        --Change the stats.
        dbms_stats.set_table_stats(user, 'TEST1', numrows => v_num_rows);

        --Generate the explain plan.
        execute immediate 'explain plan for select * from test1';

        --Gather the explain plan.
        select plan_table_output
        bulk collect into v_lines
        from table(dbms_xplan.display);

        --Output the relevant part of the explain plan.
        --The row and column numbers may be different on your system.
        dbms_output.put(rpad(v_num_rows, 22, ' ') || '   ');
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(v_lines(6), 35, 9));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

(I used the number of rows instead of cost because the number of rows is much easier to manipulate. I'm pretty sure that Oracle displays both numbers the same way.)